# PHP Regular Expression - not working.. should be

Tags: regex, date

I am trying to extract dates from a text variable.

I have created a regex which extracts 'MOST' formats of date as follows:

```
    $regexp = '#[0-9]{2,4}[-\/ ]{1}([A-Za-z]{3}|[0-9]{2})[-\/ ]{1}[0-9]{2,4}#';
preg_match_all($regexp, $output, $dates);
```

It does not however extract dates of the format '08 Aug 2012' and I do not know why.. As far as I can tell.. it should..

For now I have inserted a seperate regex which works:

```
    $regexp = '#[0-9]{2}[ ]{1}[A-Za-z]{3}[ ]{1}[0-9]{4}#';
preg_match_all($regexp, $output, $dates);
```

which is essentially the same..

It however seems pointless to have multiple regex when I need only have one.

If anyone could tell me why the first regex isnt working for such a format, and explain why, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think the 4th last symbol (/) shouldn't be there.

Comment: Looks valid, can try   [-\/\s]    rather than  [-\/ ].   Not sure if it will solved the problem or not

Comment: Sorry that is not there - typo..

Comment: Can you give some examples of dates that do work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your regexp is correct for the date format you presented. And as such it also works without problems: http://ideone.com/XxdKV

Comment: Hmm.. thanks for that - I am thus completely lost as to why it is not working.. I will continue to look into it, but if anyone has any suggestions as to what could cause such a problem it would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Obviously something is odd with your input string. If you add it to your question, maybe we can help you.

Comment: On echoing the variable it simply outputs "Creation date: 01 Aug 1998 04:00:00" - I want to simply extract the 01 Aug 1998 bit.. I cannot see a problem..?

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing, Here is an example of the working code http://ideone.com/aDAp6